# Get data where timestamp is 30th minute - pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe,

```
id    name      value    date          time
1     box       4        2020-06-08    15:15:00
2     box       44       2020-06-08    15:30:00
3     box       42       2020-06-08    15:45:00
4     box       41       2020-06-08    16:00:00
5     car       55       2020-06-08    15:15:00
6     car       33       2020-06-08    15:30:00
7     car       21       2020-06-08    15:45:00
8     car       76       2020-06-08    16:00:00
9     ace  ...
```

What I want is to obtain the 30th minute data from the above dataframe, therefore the end result will look like this

```
id    name      value    date          time
2     box       44       2020-06-08    15:30:00
6     car       33       2020-06-08    15:30:00
```

Somehow, I can't seem to figure out what to use to achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to create datetimes and compare them to the value of 30 minutes:

```
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str)).dt.minute.eq(30)]
print (df)
   id name  value        date      time
1   2  box     44  2020-06-08  15:30:00
5   6  car     33  2020-06-08  15:30:00
```

Comment: Definitely in favor of using datetime format rather than string. Although, is it faster?

Comment: Doh! This works. Although I agree with @CeliusStingher, will be better if this is in datetime datatype.

Comment: @CeliusStingher - hmm, if already converted to datetimes, then yes, if sum time of converting and selecting then not idea.

Comment: My bad, the time is already in datetime. Anyway I will accept this answer shortly. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

We can try string slice

```
df1=df[df.time.str[3:5]=='30'].copy()
```